why is the window.after() command in tkinter Python not working?
So I was working on a simple GUI stopwatch project in tkinter with a pause button (for pausing the time), a play button (for strating the time again) and a reset button (for setting the stopwatch time back to 00:00). I also added a fancy GIF background (which you can ignore) and wrote a bunch of code in order to render it as an actual animated GIF (which you can also ignore. I added a label on top of this background which was supposed to show time. also I have used this stopwatch module:(https://pypi.org/project/stopwatch.py/)
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from stopwatch import Stopwatch

stopwatch_running = False
hours = "0"
minutes = "0"
seconds = "0"

stopwatch = Stopwatch(2)
stopwatch.stop()


def pause_time():
    pass


def play_time():
    global stopwatch_running, hours, minutes, seconds
    if not stopwatch_running:
        stopwatch.start()
    stopwatch_running = True
    time = str(stopwatch)
    if len(time) > 5:
        seconds = "00"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) <= 5:
        seconds = f"0{time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 6:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 8:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"0{time[-8]}"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 9:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 11:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"0{time[-11]}"
    elif len(time) == 12:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"{time[-12] + time[-11]}"
    correct_time = f"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}"
    return correct_time


def reset_time():
    pass


def get_frame_count(gif_path):
    with Image.open(gif_path) as im:
        return im.n_frames


# Create the main window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Kawaii Stopwatch")
# window.geometry("420x400")
window.geometry("600x600")
window.configure(bg="#FFCAC8", padx=50, pady=40)

# bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="hello-kitty-kawaii.gif")
# main_bg_img = tk.Label(window, image=bg)
# main_bg_img.configure(bg="#FFCAC8")
# main_bg_img.place(x=0, y=0)
# main_bg_img.grid(row=1, column=1)

# ------------------------------for making the GIF image show as an animation--(ignore)-------------
bg_gif = "hello-kitty-kawaii.gif"
bg_gif_frames = get_frame_count(gif_path=bg_gif)

im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=bg_gif, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(bg_gif_frames)]

count = 0

anim = None


def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]
    bg_gif_label.configure(image=im2)

    count += 1

    if count == bg_gif_frames:
        count = 0

    anim = window.after(100, lambda: animation(count=count))


def stop_animation():
    global anim
    window.after_cancel(anim)


# ------------------section for making GIF appear as an actual GIF ended-------------------

bg_gif_label = tk.Label(image="")
bg_gif_label.configure(bg="#FFCAC8")
bg_gif_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

pause_button = tk.Button(text="Pause", command=pause_time and stop_animation, bg="#BFECFF")
pause_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

play_button = tk.Button(text="Play", command=play_time and (lambda: animation(count)), bg="#BFECFF")
play_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

reset_button = tk.Button(text="Reset", command=reset_time(), bg="green")
reset_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

time_label = tk.Label(text="00:00:00", font="Consolas")
time_label.grid(row=1, column=1)



window.after(80, func=time_label.config(text=play_time()))
animation(count)  # line of code related to GIF animation

window.mainloop()


Now, I defined a function called play_time() for returning the correct time in the desirable format everytime it was called. I used window.after() method of tkinter to configure the time label on my window and update it to the returned string of play_time() function after every 80 miliseconds. But the window.after() method is not updating my time at all. Here's my code:
here is the result I am getting:
here is the result i am getting
note that the result is same even after I click the play_button...
if you want a minimal code which only has the window.after() error then here it is:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
from stopwatch import Stopwatch

stopwatch_running = False
hours = "0"
minutes = "0"
seconds = "0"

stopwatch = Stopwatch(2)
stopwatch.stop()

def pause_time():
    pass


def play_time():
    global stopwatch_running, hours, minutes, seconds
    if not stopwatch_running:
        stopwatch.start()
    stopwatch_running = True
    time = str(stopwatch)
    if len(time) > 5:
        seconds = "00"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) <= 5:
        seconds = f"0{time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 6:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"00"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 8:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"0{time[-8]}"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 9:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"00"
    elif len(time) == 11:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"0{time[-11]}"
    elif len(time) == 12:
        seconds = f"{time[-6] + time[-5]}"
        minutes = f"{time[-9] + time[-8]}"
        hours = f"{time[-12] + time[-11]}"
    correct_time = f"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}"
    return correct_time


def reset_time():
    pass


def get_frame_count(gif_path):
    with Image.open(gif_path) as im:
        return im.n_frames


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("My Kawaii Stopwatch")

window.geometry("600x600")
window.configure(bg="#FFCAC8", padx=50, pady=40)


pause_button = tk.Button(text="Pause", command=pause_time and stop_animation, bg="#BFECFF")
pause_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

play_button = tk.Button(text="Play", command=play_time and (lambda: animation(count)), bg="#BFECFF")
play_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

reset_button = tk.Button(text="Reset", command=reset_time(), bg="green")
reset_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

time_label = tk.Label(text="00:00:00", font="Consolas")
time_label.grid(row=1, column=1)



window.after(80, func=time_label.config(text=play_time()))
animation(count)  # line of code related to GIF animation

window.mainloop()


`
Guys, I have like tried everything, atleast everything I could understand by watching thod Youtube videos but it is still not working. I think I need expertise of some sinear programmer for solving issue so please hep me out!

You need to pass a lambda or a function pointer as the parameter. You currently are passing the result of the function call time_label.config(...).

Also, you cannot do things like this: command=pause_time and stop_animation. Instead, you must do e.g. command=lambda: pause_time() and stop_animation().

Can you please elaborate the first comment a little? Or atleast show an example how should I do it instead?

anyways thanks for the additional debugging and also I did put lambda in the code like this: window.after(80, func=lambda: time_label.config(text=play_time())) but it is still not working (T_T) i.e. still showing the same result...

Can you update the question? I can only repeat the previous comments. The argument to command has to be a function. Maybe this explains the problem: What is the difference between a function call and function reference?. The question is about JavaScript but it's the same concept. command=reset_time() doesn't pass the function reference. It passes the returned None value.

command=pause_time and stop_animation is not what you expect. It returns the reference to stop_animation. You have to pass one function that combines the return values of these functions.

anim = window.after(100, lambda: animation(count=count)) is correct. It creates a lambda function and passes the reference. window.after(80, func=time_label.config(text=play_time())) is wrong. It calls time_label.config(text=play_time()) and passes the returned value.

This question is similar to: What is the difference between a function call and function reference?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

after(delay, func) schedules to call the specified function func once after the specified delay (in ms).  So if you want to keep calling the function periodically, you need to call .after() again inside the function.
Below is an example:
def update_play_time():
    time_label.config(text=play_time()) # update label with play time
    window.after(80, update_play_time) # schedule next execution

window.after(80, update_play_time) # start the after loop

Also you can simplify play_time() as below:
def play_time():
    global stopwatch_running, hours, minutes, seconds

    if not stopwatch_running:
        stopwatch.start()
    stopwatch_running = True

    seconds = int(stopwatch.duration)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

    hours = f'{hours:02}'
    minutes = f'{minutes:02}'
    seconds = f'{seconds:02}'

    return f"{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}"

